# Random access InputStream using AES CTR mode in android

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I  am unable to find any working  example for AES CTR encryption for random access. Can someone guide me how to use the counter in CTR MODE also how to implement jumping to a specific position in the stream?

The default stream implementation (`CipherInputStream`) doesn't skip the stream and it corrupts the plain text.

I am trying to decrypt encrypted Video file stored on sdcard in Android. An embedded HTTP file server decrypts it on the fly. Everything is working fine until a user performs a seek within the video: the video stops immediately because it receives corrupt video stream.

I am using following code to initialize and encrypt/ decrypt stream (for sake of simplicity i hard coded the keys. it will not be hard coded in production)

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    bb.put("1234567891230000".getBytes());
    byte[] ivString = bb.array();

    // INITIALISATION
    String keyString = "1234567812345678";
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivString);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes(), "AES");

    // FOR ENCRYPTION
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(ivString));
    Inputstream encrypted_is = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);

    // FOR DECRYPTION
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(ivString));
            Inputstream decrypted_is = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
```

Comment: Try posting some code. It will be easier to help you

Comment: "Random access input stream" is a contradiction in terms. It is either random access or a stream.

Answer (score 9):

You should not implement this using a stream. A stream is used for sequential access to data. Skipping should only be used for jumping short distances forward and mark/reset only for jumping small distances back.

Using a file [map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) is probably the most efficient. For a slightly easier approach but less efficient approach you could use [`RandomAccessFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) instead. You should furthermore use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding")` using an "IV" that is set to the counter you expect at the location you start within the file.

---

Sample code for using CTR with offset:

```
private static final int AES_BLOCK_SIZE = 16;

public static final void jumpToOffset(final Cipher c,
        final SecretKey aesKey, final IvParameterSpec iv, final long offset) {
    if (!c.getAlgorithm().toUpperCase().startsWith("AES/CTR")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid algorithm, only AES/CTR mode supported");
    }

    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid offset");
    }

    final int skip = (int) (offset % AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    final IvParameterSpec calculatedIVForOffset = calculateIVForOffset(iv,
            offset - skip);
    try {
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, calculatedIVForOffset);
        final byte[] skipBuffer = new byte[skip];
        c.update(skipBuffer, 0, skip, skipBuffer);
        Arrays.fill(skipBuffer, (byte) 0);
    } catch (ShortBufferException | InvalidKeyException
            | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private static IvParameterSpec calculateIVForOffset(final IvParameterSpec iv,
        final long blockOffset) {
    final BigInteger ivBI = new BigInteger(1, iv.getIV());
    final BigInteger ivForOffsetBI = ivBI.add(BigInteger.valueOf(blockOffset
            / AES_BLOCK_SIZE));

    final byte[] ivForOffsetBA = ivForOffsetBI.toByteArray();
    final IvParameterSpec ivForOffset;
    if (ivForOffsetBA.length >= AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
        ivForOffset = new IvParameterSpec(ivForOffsetBA, ivForOffsetBA.length - AES_BLOCK_SIZE,
                AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    } else {
        final byte[] ivForOffsetBASized = new byte[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
        System.arraycopy(ivForOffsetBA, 0, ivForOffsetBASized, AES_BLOCK_SIZE
                - ivForOffsetBA.length, ivForOffsetBA.length);
        ivForOffset = new IvParameterSpec(ivForOffsetBASized);
    }

    return ivForOffset;
}
```

Comment: 1 - I used AES/CTR/NoPadding for encryption.how can i set counter in IV to start from specific value.
2 - How to get plain bytes at a skipped position.(decrypt encrypted block from a specific position).

thank you

Comment: Can you please quote few lines of implementation.
i am coding in Java but unable to find any code snippet.

Comment: Ok but thanks alot for taking time to answer my question. Its a big help for me :)

Comment: Any progress on this? I am really really stuck.

Comment: @frostymarvelous As you asked so nicely.

Comment: Very much appreciated. I really do need to learn cryptography. I have a mooc scheduled this month.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes you were mentioned here https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2467#issuecomment-283471153 if you'd like to weigh in

Comment: Very good code sample for CTR random seek in encrypted data, but I can't figure out the GCM mode.