# PHP aes-128-gcm openssl_decrypt only works after using openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl, aes-gcm

I have to decrypt aes-128-gcm encrypted data I get from an external party. Since openssl_decrypt never returned any data, I tried to encrypt the elsewhere decrypted data myself, to see if that works and in fact I receive the same encrypted data I try to decrypt. Therefore I know, all my parameters are correct. So I played around with my PHP code and come to the strange conclusion, that decrypting the data only works for me, after I encrypt the plaintext?!?
Does anybody have any idea what's going on here?

thanks,
Harry

```
<?php

$method='aes-128-gcm';

$key = hex2bin('0748BEF58E04D5917ED0B9B558628265');

//echo "iv_length: ". openssl_cipher_iv_length($method)."<br>";
$iv = hex2bin('534D5367700114E600102D29');
$tag = NULL;

$enc = hex2bin('09E89C959CD513057787832142E6796E1F6DE55CBA8E5CEC6E16AA635B3B102DDB22D85841923DDC2EE3052027945DFD00D025A0A5D0EB385E0033DD28037D80B47522B3DB310B01871474686B609D2DA15864785895DF2BE887');
$plain = hex2bin('0F00102D280C07E4081F01103B1000FF8880020C09060006190900FF090D323232313230323031323735360904103B1000090507E4081F0106004C48DF06000000CB06000089CF06000E61E7060000020A060000000009000900');

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($enc, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plain, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
$decrypted2 = openssl_decrypt($enc, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);

echo "plain: ".bin2hex($plain)."<br>";
echo "enc: ".bin2hex($encrypted)."<br>";
echo "dec: ".bin2hex($decrypted)."<br>";
echo "dec2: ".bin2hex($decrypted2)."\n";

while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
    echo $msg . "<br>\n";
?>
```

OUTPUT:

plain:
0f00102d280c07e4081f01103b1000ff8880020c09060006190900ff090d323232313230323031323735360904103b1000090507e4081f0106004c48df06000000cb06000089cf06000e61e7060000020a060000000009000900

enc:
09e89c959cd513057787832142e6796e1f6de55cba8e5cec6e16aa635b3b102ddb22d85841923ddc2ee3052027945dfd00d025a0a5d0eb385e0033dd28037d80b47522b3db310b01871474686b609d2da15864785895df2be887

dec:

dec2:
0f00102d280c07e4081f01103b1000ff8880020c09060006190900ff090d323232313230323031323735360904103b1000090507e4081f0106004c48df06000000cb06000089cf06000e61e7060000020a060000000009000900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. You are using the AES algorithm in mode `GCM` and that means that the ciphertext is secured against modification with an "authentication tag" or short "tag". This tag is generated when encrypting a plaintext with AES-GCM and needs to be available when decrypting the ciphertext.

In your code you provide an empty $tag-variable to the decrypt-function and the decryption fails. When generating a "new" plaintext with openssl_encrypt your $tag-variable gets filled with a tag. Now you are decrypting again and provide this tag to the openssl_decrypt-function and the decryption works like expected.

So you need to get the value of the $tag from the third party to successfully decrypt the ciphertext back to plaintext.

Using this small change in the sourcecode the program provides the $tag:

```
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($enc, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
echo "tag: ".bin2hex($tag)."<br>" . PHP_EOL;
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plain, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
echo "tag: ".bin2hex($tag)."<br>" . PHP_EOL;
$decrypted2 = openssl_decrypt($enc, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
```

result:

```
tag: <br>
tag: 9268f3568512fc9f15075096c1b47902<br>
```

**Edit with solution**

According to this answer of @Maarten Bodewes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49244840/8166854) there is a chance of decypting "aes gcm"
encrypted data without a authentication tag because

```
AES GCM = AES CTR + AuthTag
```

Changing your source code as below decrypts the password as expected in the first run, I added manually the hex-data '00000002' to the iv:

```
plain:  0f00102d280c07e4081f01103b1000ff8880020c09060006190900ff090d323232313230323031323735360904103b1000090507e4081f0106004c48df06000000cb06000089cf06000e61e7060000020a060000000009000900<br>
enc:    09e89c959cd513057787832142e6796e1f6de55cba8e5cec6e16aa635b3b102ddb22d85841923ddc2ee3052027945dfd00d025a0a5d0eb385e0033dd28037d80b47522b3db310b01871474686b609d2da15864785895df2be887<br>
decCtr: 0f00102d280c07e4081f01103b1000ff8880020c09060006190900ff090d323232313230323031323735360904103b1000090507e4081f0106004c48df06000000cb06000089cf06000e61e7060000020a060000000009000900<br>
decGcm: 0f00102d280c07e4081f01103b1000ff8880020c09060006190900ff090d323232313230323031323735360904103b1000090507e4081f0106004c48df06000000cb06000089cf06000e61e7060000020a060000000009000900
```

code:

```
<?php
$method='aes-128-gcm';
$key = hex2bin('0748BEF58E04D5917ED0B9B558628265');
$iv = hex2bin('534D5367700114E600102D29');
$tag = NULL;
$enc = hex2bin('09E89C959CD513057787832142E6796E1F6DE55CBA8E5CEC6E16AA635B3B102DDB22D85841923DDC2EE3052027945DFD00D025A0A5D0EB385E0033DD28037D80B47522B3DB310B01871474686B609D2DA15864785895DF2BE887');
$plain = hex2bin('0F00102D280C07E4081F01103B1000FF8880020C09060006190900FF090D323232313230323031323735360904103B1000090507E4081F0106004C48DF06000000CB06000089CF06000E61E7060000020A060000000009000900');

//$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($enc, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
$methodCtr = 'aes-128-ctr';
$ivCtr = hex2bin('534D5367700114E600102D2900000002');
$decryptedCtr = openssl_decrypt($enc, $methodCtr, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ivCtr);
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plain, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
echo "tag: ".bin2hex($tag)."<br>" . PHP_EOL;
$decryptedGcm = openssl_decrypt($enc, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);

echo "plain:  ".bin2hex($plain)."<br>" . PHP_EOL;
echo "enc:    ".bin2hex($encrypted)."<br>" . PHP_EOL;
echo "decCtr: ".bin2hex($decryptedCtr)."<br>" . PHP_EOL;
echo "decGcm: ".bin2hex($decryptedGcm)."\n" . PHP_EOL;
while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
    echo $msg . "<br>\n";
?>
```

Comment: That explains the behaviour of PHP. But the original encryption is done according to DLMS/COSEM Green Book 
https://www.dlms.com/files/Green_Book_Edition_9-Excerpt.pdf
According to paragraph 9.2.7.2.4 AES-GCM supports authentication only, encryption only and encryption+authentication. Therefore in encrpytion only mode, no tag is needed and defined as a 12 byte filled with 00 -> therefore my empty $tag value, since $tag = hex2bin('000000000000000000000000') made no difference.

Comment: Great! I already suspected it maybe can be solved with CTR-mode, but wouldn't have found the info for the additional IV-Bytes.