# Openssl Encrypting and signing data using symmetric key in php

Tags: c#, php, json

```
The input is base64

byte[] encryptedContent = _crypto.AESEncrypt(input, key);
                string bContent = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedContent);
                byte[] bSignature = _crypto.RSASign(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bContent));
                request.Data.Content = bContent;
                request.Data.Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(bSignature);
```

Hello can someone help me to convert the above C# code to a php. Am trying to send an encrypted and a signed content to the server. but I get Data decryption error.

```
// encryption code 
$encrypt_json = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($Pjoson),
        "AES-128-GCM",
        "$SMKey");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP aes-128-gcm openssl\_decrypt only works after using openssl\_encrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700683/php-aes-128-gcm-openssl-decrypt-only-works-after-using-openssl-encrypt)

Comment: @C1sc0 am trying to convert the above C# code to php. they told m to use the above sample for my php code.