# How to decrypt with Bouncy Castle a private key encrypted with CKM_AES_GCM on a HSM?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

In order to verify an `RSA` private key wrapping operation performed on a HSM, I try to decrypt it using Bouncy Castle. The private key is encrypted using an hybrid encryption scheme:

1. A temporary `AES` session key is generated
2. This session key is used to encrypt the target private using `CKM_RSA_PKCS` (for example) mechanism
3. The session key is itself encrypted using a private master key stored in the HSM using `CKM_AES_GCM` mechanism.

The HSM returns the encrypted keys. As I have access to the software versions of the private master key and the on-the-fly generated `AES` key, I am able to decrypt the session key and verify that it is the expected one.
Unfortunately, I cannot decrypt the wrapped private key with the session key and BC. It fails with the exception `javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed`.

This error seems to be related to the authenticated tag that is part of the returned cryptogram. Indeed, when I try to decrypt the private key ignoring the authentication, that is increasing the counter and using `CKM_AES_CTR` mechanism following [Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes) [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228671/aes-gcm-decryption-bypassing-authentication-in-java/49244840#49244840) I successfully get access to the private key.

Could someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong when decrypting?

Here is some information that could be useful:

- The HSM is an UTIMACO SecurityServer Simulator version 4.60.0.0
- The Java code used to decrypt is the following:

```
String secretKeyString = "BIh3JY8bSvmikYWOm1qk6w==";
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(secretKeyString), "AES");
String iv = "6rLMygOozSqr7Zqx";
byte[] ivBytes = Base64.decode(iv);
int TAG_SIZE = 128;

String wrappedPrivateKey = "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";

final byte[] cryptogram = HexFormat.of().parseHex(wrappedPrivateKey);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
final GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_SIZE, ivBytes);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmParameterSpec);
final byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(cryptogram);
```

Comment: For a correct authentication, AAD (additional authenticated data) may be required. If so, these must be specified with `cipher.updateAAD(...)`. Whether AAD is required and what data is involved can possibly be found in the process description.

Comment: I based my test on PKCS#11 standards, which describes the AAD parameter as optional in CKM_GCM_PARAMS structure.
The fact that the HSM returns, without any error, something that can be decrypted makes me think that it should not be required. But the documentation of the HSM is rather vague on this subject.
I'll try with AAD if it was required and let you know

Comment: Correct, AAD are optional, i.e. AAD do not have to be used during encryption. But *if* AAD were used during encryption, then they *must* also be used during decryption. Otherwise a different tag will result and the authentication will fail. Of course, I cannot say whether any are used in the case of your encryption.

Comment: @Topaco, When I add AAD bytes to the wrap parameters, everything works fine when decrypting with BC, using `cipher.updateAAD(...)`. Then it means that either AAD is required by the HSM which produces a bad authentication tag without it or BC is unable to correctly handle this tag without AAD

Comment: @Topaco For the first tests, I do not include AAD in the parameters passed to the HSM for CKM_AES_GCM mechanism (only IV and tagBits), that's why I do not handle it in BC decryption.

Answer (score 0):

As @Topaco said, it was a problem of AAD. I thought that a `null` AAD was supplied and in fact it was an empty byte array, what is slighlty different ;)

With the right input, everything works well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).